# How do I reference a Kendo Grid inside a Kendo Tab Strip?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

Template for the tab:

```
<div id="parentTabStrip">
            <ul>
                <li class="k-state-active">Titles</li>
                <li>Commercials</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="titlesGrid"></div>
            <div id="commercialsGrid"></div>
        </div>
```

I can't simply do `$('#titlesGrid').data('kendoGrid');` because that's not what the HTML looks like after the tab and grid has been instantiated.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //on page load, the grid is built. 
            var year = $("#txtYear").val();
            createTitlesGrid(year);

            $("#txtYear").on("change", function()
            {
                //on the click of a button, I do the following...

                //get the tabStrip (this works)
                var tabStrip = $('#parentTabStrip').data("kendoTabStrip");

                //now I need to reference the actual grid. The thing is, I don't know how to find it through the tab (this does not work).
                var grid = tabStrip.select("titlesGrid");

                //once I have the grid, I then need to destroy it.   
                grid.destroy();

                //finally, I get the value entered by the user in the text box and build the grid again.
                var year = this.value;
                createTitlesGrid(year);

            });
</script>
```

Can anyone give me a hand on this. There's a specific way to reference objects in Kendo and I'm having a hard time doing it.

Again, what I need to do is reference a Kendo Grid that's inside a tab so I can destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, it doesn't matter if the grid is inside a tab or not.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

How do you create the Kendo grid and tabstrip?

Comment: Unfortunately your statement isn't accurate. If I do what you said, I'll get a NULL. I get a NULL for this because there's no such thing as #titlesGridon the actual HTML ... AFTER it has been instantiated. To start with, the DIV IS there... but after the page is loaded, there's no such thing as #titlesGrid anymore.